# How do I use fscanf to read from a file with white spaces in C?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm trying to read from a file in the format:

```
name (str)
duration (int)
path (str)
filter (int)
```

this format can repeat multiple times.

I tried using:

```
file = fopen(path, "r");
curr = fscanf(file, "%s %d %s %d", currentName, &currentDuration, currentPath, &currentFilter);

while (curr == 4) {
    // do something with the info

    currentName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN);
    currentPath = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN);
    curr = fscanf(file, "%s %d %s %d", currentName, &currentDuration, currentPath, &currentFilter);
}
```

(everything is free somewhere else, it isn't an issue)
overall this code works well, but when one of the strings has a whitespace in it, it stops.
How do I change that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to improve your data format. How do you tell whether the `2` in `"/abc/dir 2"` is part of the string or part of the int following it? Your data format needs to be more clearly specified to delimit the values in an unambiguous manner. Or is it one value per line (it's hard to tell for sure from your description)?

Comment: in `fscanf()` you need to know and specify what charcters are you reading exactly including white spaces. if you need to overcome this, use `fgets()`. read about fgets in man pages. [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)

Comment: By using `%[^\n]` instead of `%s` but if all your data is on a single line there will be a problem if there are say 6 "words" and 4 format specifiers.